# Which kind of use cases are ideal for MC Data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sales-cloud

We are currently planning and designing a huge migration of data from a custom-made application to Salesforce, integrated with Marketing Cloud.

My main concern is to know **when is it convenient to migrate certain data to Marketing Cloud Data Extensions and when should it persist in Sales Cloud**.

I understand that all sales data and certain marketing data has to live in Sales Cloud, like campaigns, campaign members, etc... but, for example, if I have **a set of fields that are related to only specific subset of campaigns**, should I then create fields in campaign members or should I create Data Extensions in MC and use AMPScript in my emails?

I am aware that this is in some sense opinion-based, but I'm sure there's a set of best practices regarding when to place stuff in one place or another.

Some of my colleagues favor putting all the data in Sales Cloud and creating 10-20 fields in Campaign Member and, if in a year we need more fields, do it again, just for the sake of having all data in the same place.

On the other hand, I don't think it's scalable because if along 5 years the client creates 10 new campaigns and each of those campaigns require 10 more fields we would end up with a massive Campaign Member entity.

So, in a nutshell, if you could help me with this issue, even if it's not with specific technical data, it would be highly appreciated :-)